# Complex logarithm for Stirling's formula

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory

In complex analysis, The Stirling formula,

\begin{align*}
\Gamma(s) = \left(\frac{2\pi}{s}\right)^{1/2}\left(\frac{s}{e}\right)^{s}\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{|s|}\right)\right)
\end{align*}
is valid in the angle $|\arg(s)|\leq \pi-\varepsilon$ with the implied constant depening on $\varepsilon$.

Hence for $s=\sigma+it$, $t\ne 0$, $\sigma$ fixed
\begin{align*}
\Gamma(\sigma+it) = \sqrt{2\pi} (it)^{\sigma-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}|t|} \left(\frac{|t|}{e}\right)^{it}\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{|t|}\right)\right).
\end{align*}

If I consider complex logarithm then I can write

\begin{align*}
\log\Gamma(\sigma+it) = \log|\Gamma(\sigma+it)|+i\arg(\Gamma(\sigma+it))
\end{align*}

In absolute value we have
\begin{align*}
|\Gamma(\sigma+it)| = \sqrt{2\pi}|t|^{\sigma-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}|t|} \left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{|t|}\right)\right).
\end{align*}

How to calculate $\arg(\Gamma(\sigma+it))$?

Comment: mm, what exactly do you need?

Comment: A similar formula for $\arg(\Gamma(s))$, like we have for $|\Gamma(s)|$.

Comment: i meant what do you need it for ultimately.  but anyway, $t^{it}=e^{itlog t}$ so the argument of that is $tlog t$

Comment: Nothing. I am just trying to figure it out. I found the formula for the real part from stack exchange. How to calculate the argument for the rest of the thing? I mean what about the terms $|t|^{\sigma-\frac{1}{2}}$?

Comment: that's real :D  you only need to worry about powers with $i$

Comment: I am sorry I worte $|t|^{\sigma-\frac{1}{2}}$ instead of $(it)^{\sigma-\frac{1}{2}}$. Doesn't that count as the imaginary part?

Comment: ye, now take the imaginary part of $i^{\sigma -1/2}$.  (write it as $e^{(...)\log i}=e^{...|i|+...arg(i)}...$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $\sigma$ lies in a fixed interval and $t\to+\infty$, a convenient version of Stirling's formula (See equation 4.12.1 of Titchmarh's *The theory of the Riemann zeta-function*) is stated as follows:

$$
\log\Gamma(\sigma+it)=\left(\sigma+it-\frac12\right)\log(it)-it+\frac12\log2\pi+\mathcal O\left(1\over t\right)
$$

Taking imaginary components on both side gives

$$
\arg\Gamma(\sigma+it)=t\log t-t+\left(\sigma-\frac12\right)\frac\pi2+\mathcal O\left(1\over t\right)
$$